# How to download a picture and save temporaly the file in the application

Tags: android, download, project, directory, fullscreen

I am developing a android application and I try to show a picture in full screen.

For do this I use the code of this exemple:
https://github.com/jasonpolites/gesture-imageview

The interfice xml of the activity is this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout 
 xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 xmlns:gesture-image="http://schemas.polites.com/android"
 android:id="@+id/layout"
 android:layout_width="fill_parent"
 android:layout_height="fill_parent"
 android:orientation="vertical" 
 android:background="#000000">
  <com.polites.android.GestureImageView
    android:id="@+id/image"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
    android:scaleType="centerInside" 
    gesture-image:min-scale="0.75"
    gesture-image:max-scale="10.0"
    android:src="@drawable/image"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

But i don't want use the picture of /drawable folder, i want use a img download of url.

How i can't download the picture, put in some place of the memory, or some folder, and put this path in the xml File?

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

You can't do that. The `res` directory files of an apk are `READ ONLY`. You can simply grab the image url, save it in internal storage as file and later render it. You can save the image in a specific filepath you want to. And then show it programmatically which will replace the images of drawable in the imageview.

Answer (score 0):

If you already download the image, try the code :

```
GestureImageView image = (GestureImageView)findViewById(R.id.image);
Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imageFilePath);
image.setImageBitmap(bmp);
```

Or you can try the following :

```
GestureImageView image = (GestureImageView)findViewById(R.id.image);
InputStrean is = new URL("http://.../.../xxx.jpg").openConnection().getInputStream();
Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is);
image.setImageBitmap(bmp);
```

Comment: Thanks, i tried this code with the class GestureImageView and don't work correctly, but i can use this code with one ImageView "full parent " and works, i only have problems with the margins.